# Cannot boot Ubuntu 20.4 from USB drive on Insignia touchscreen laptop (originally running Windows 10)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I am new to Ubuntu, and am converting some of my devices,
I recently inserted a USB drive, onto it formatted (in FAT32) the latest version of Ubuntu, into a relatively new, Insignia touchscreen laptop from Best Buy. This is an important detail, as they seem to have very strange firmware settings, and they are the hardware brand, not HP or Dell.
I went into advanced recovery boot, and tried booting into the USB "EUFI Partition 1" option from there.
The USB light flashed, and it simply booted into Windows 10 again. Strange.
So I went into the actual UEFI firmware settings, and disabled every other boot option (Windows Recovery, Windows Boot Manager, and Embedded UEFI Shell). And tried advanced recovery after that. Windows.
Then tried booting again directly onto the USB Partition 1 option from the "boot override" option in, I believe, security maybe, in firmware settings. Still Windows.
I don't have much knowledge of firmware or OS booting, but I have tried everything my experience has given me, even going into the security and updates settings of the actual Windows OS.
I have also disabled secure boot, still nothing.
I asked this question on Tech Republic, more generally, and one person said I may need the 'UEFI files in the first partition'.
Sorry for the long post,
Thanks for any reply or help,
antho-spade

Comment: Did you write the Ubuntu ISO as a file on the thumb-drive (thus it's not bootable), or burn it (expand the ISO to files) to the thumb-drive?  (where the FAT32 doesn't matter being overwritten by the expansion/burn). Does it boot on other boxes? as it sounds to me like you copied the ISO as a file, rather than write as a bootable ISO to your thumb-drive.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview
These 2 tutorials should say all you need to know Tell us how you go. Please reply with @UsernameOfYourTarget

Answer (score 0):

Use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to make a bootable Pendrive of ubuntu. 
Use the fat32 format option.

Then go to boot option and turn off secure boot in your boot menu. then reboot to your boot menu. Select the Pendrive from the boot menu. I hope it will solve your problem.